# SVG. Center the text inside <g> tag

Tags: xml, svg

There is an auto-generated image with a chess board, pieces in squares are displayed using utf-8 misc symbols, so they are text, each square is a group `<g>` tag, which contains:

- `<rect>`,
- `<path>` - border
- and `<text></text>`, if there is a piece inside a square

Here is svg markup, for convinience I left two squares and removed border symbols:

```html
<svg id="chessBoard"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 567.93 567.93">
<defs>
    <style>
    .cls-1{fill:#a73a2f;stroke:#a73a2f;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .cls-2{fill:#83261d;}.cls-3{fill:#f2c48d;}
    .wp{font-size:50px;letter-spacing:0em;fill:#c38748}
    .bp{font-size:50px;letter-spacing:0em;fill:#150503}
    </style>
</defs>
<rect id="border" class="cls-1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="566.93" height="566.93"/>
<g id="B1">
    <!--B1-->
    <rect class="cls-2" x="114.62" y="454.78" width="55.22" height="55.21"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M176.86,461.76v53.73H123.13V461.76h53.73m1.48-1.48H121.65V517h56.69V460.28Z" transform="translate(-7.76 -6.23)"/>
    <text class="bp" transform="translate(117.62 501.78)">&#x265C;</text>
</g>
<g id="A1">
    <!--A1-->
    <rect class="cls-3" x="57.69" y="454.54" width="55.69" height="55.69"/>
    <path class="cls-3" d="M120.65,461.28V516H66V461.28h54.69m1-1H65V517h56.69V460.28Z" transform="translate(-7.76 -6.23)"/>
    <text class="bp" transform="translate(60.69 501.54)">&#x265C;</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

The question is how is it possible to align text, hence the pieces, to the center of a sqaure `<g>` tag, in a way that does not involve changing 64 numbers in `translate()`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: why not use a stroke as the border, the path seems complicated and doesn't add much. Then to your main point if you transform the <g> elements all the contents can be identical for individual pieces such as pawns. You could use <use> and <symbol> elements for the pieces rather than <g>

Comment: FYI,  for creating a fully interactive HTML5 Chessboard  **one** HTML tag is enough: `` <chessmeister-board></chessmeister-board>`` https://chessmeister.github.io/ Creating the whole board **in SVG** is a pain when you want to add drag/drop.. which is so much easier with HTML Nodes positioned in a CSS grid

Comment: To position text; add a 100% width Path inside a square; then position with ``textPath``: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291003/add-text-to-svg-path-dynamically/67297788#67297788  And, as said, its easier to create 64 SVGs in a CSS grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach IMO is to have a simple standard square design.  Make it so that the thing sits at the origin (0, 0), and then move the whole group to its final position.
That way every square is the same apart from `class` and text content.

The piece position problem is easily solved now.  Every `<text>` element has the same `x` and `y`, and you use `text-anchor="middle"` to centre the piece horizontally.  The height works fine because all the pieces are the same height (more or less).

```html
<svg id="chessBoard"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 567.93 567.93">
<defs>
    <style>
    .cls-1{fill:#a73a2f;stroke:#a73a2f;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .cls-2{fill:#83261d;}.cls-3{fill:#f2c48d;}
    .wp{font-size:50px;letter-spacing:0em;fill:#c38748}
    .bp{font-size:50px;letter-spacing:0em;fill:#150503}
    </style>
</defs>
<rect id="border" class="cls-1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="566.93" height="566.93"/>
<g id="B1" transform="translate(114.62, 454.54)">
    <!--B1-->
    <rect class="cls-2" width="55.69" height="55.69"/>
    <text class="bp" x="27.85" y="47" text-anchor="middle">&#x265C;</text>
</g>
<g id="A1" transform="translate(57.69, 454.54)">
    <!--A1-->
    <rect class="cls-3" width="55.69" height="55.69"/>
    <text class="bp" x="27.85" y="47" text-anchor="middle">&#x265A;</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution, works great and defenitelly saved me a lot of time.