# Add text and center inside svg code in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-hooks

I am trying to add text inside svg to create a nice looks.
Here is my svg file globalSVG.js:

```
const Token = () => {
  const [teamCredits, setTeamCredits] = useState(0);
  const fetchTeamCredits = async () => {
    try {
      // Fetch credits for user
      const res = await axios.get("api/v1/teams/credits");
      // Set teams credit for user
      setTeamCredits(res.data.teamCredits);
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.message === "Request failed with status code 401") {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        throw err;
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // On mount
    fetchTeamCredits();
  }, []);

  return (
    <svg
      width="35"
      height="22"
      viewBox="0 0 35 22"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <text>{teamCredits}</text>
      <path
        d="M31.7059 11C31.7059 11.7128 31.982 12.3963 32.4733 12.9003C32.9647 13.4044 33.6311 13.6875 34.326 13.6875V19.0625C34.326 19.7753 34.05 20.4588 33.5586 20.9628C33.0672 21.4669 32.4008 21.75 31.7059 21.75H3.2939C2.59901 21.75 1.93259 21.4669 1.44123 20.9628C0.94987 20.4588 0.673828 19.7753 0.673828 19.0625V13.6875C1.36871 13.6875 2.03514 13.4044 2.5265 12.9003C3.01786 12.3963 3.2939 11.7128 3.2939 11C3.2939 10.2872 3.01786 9.60365 2.5265 9.09965C2.03514 8.59565 1.36871 8.3125 0.673828 8.3125V2.9375C0.673828 2.22473 0.94987 1.54115 1.44123 1.03715C1.93259 0.533146 2.59901 0.25 3.2939 0.25H31.7059C32.4008 0.25 33.0672 0.533146 33.5586 1.03715C34.05 1.54115 34.326 2.22473 34.326 2.9375V8.3125C33.6311 8.3125 32.9647 8.59565 32.4733 9.09965C31.982 9.60365 31.7059 10.2872 31.7059 11Z"
        fill="white"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};
```

and here is my page to show svg:

```
import { CloudUpload, Token } from "styles/globalSVG";
    <Button className={classes.applyButton} id="apply-button">
      <Token />
      <span className={classes.applyText}>Apply</span>
    </Button>
```

Here is how my project looks:

[image]

How can I achieve text inside svg code?

Comment: you probably want an x and certainly a y attribute to give your text a position.

Comment: what x and y can do ?

Comment: You can mess around by X,Y positioning text; or use guide-path to position (dynamic) text: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291003/add-text-to-svg-path-dynamically/67297788#67297788