# HTML SVG Path Text in middle

Tags: html, angular, svg

I am working on SVG image created by multiple path tag.
What i want is to write down some dynamic text inside and center of the path tag.
I tried the title tag but it is working as a tooltip.
I want the text to be there at all time after assignment.

Below is the code snippet of my HTML file

```
<div class="main">
    <svg id="map" class="me-svg" viewBox="10 -25 1000 870">
        <path (click)="showSomePopUp(item)" class="select" *ngFor="let item of myData" [attr.d]="item.d"
            [attr.title]="item.title" [attr.id]="item.id" [attr.class]="item.myCheck=='true'?'red':null">
            <title *ngIf="item.myCheck=='true'">{{item.title}},
                {{item.size}}</title>
        </path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Below is the code from ts file :

```
myData: DataInterface[] = [{
  id: "IN", "text":"default", "title": "India", size: 20, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 736.102,436.797l0.066,0.189l-0.062,0.104l-0.123,0.016l-0.076,-0.096l-0.009,-0.112l0.07,-0.073l0.066,-0.038L736.102,436.797zM735.947,426.258l-0.057,-0.037l-0.045,0.014l-0.042,0.05l0.018,0.398l0.089,-0.186L735.947,426.258zM735.833,430.496l-0.14,-0.13l-0.018,0.234l-0.107,0.115l0.137,0.071l0.137,-0.057l-0.017,-0.085L735.833,430.496zM736.676,427.431l-0.071,-0.892l-0.221,-0.263l0.066,-0.094l0.116,-0.25l0.149,-0.077l0.107,-0.188l0.065,-0.191l0.021,-0.087l-0.162,-0.241l0.17,-0.185l-0.028,-0.103l-0.012,-0.313l-0.093,0.004l-0.294,0.167l-0.188,0.366l0.008,0.366l-0.144,0.546l0.062,0.106l-0.067,0.354l-0.151,0.166l-0.036,0.118l0.054,0.316l-0.076,0.153l-0.032,0.212l-0.005,0.525l0.043,0.061l0.122,0.095l0.029,0.219l-0.053,0.029l-0.21,0.002l-0.051,0.064l-0.101,0.229l-0.024,0.28l-0.068,0.184l-0.115,0.054l-0.092,0.163l0.072,0.114l0.045,0.328l0.261,0.511l0.091,0.075l0.062,-0.067l0.117,-0.293l0.007,-0.357l0.086,-0.313l-0.002,-0.122l-0.093,-0.065l-0.045,-0.149l0.107,-0.12l0.036,-0.127l0.191,-0.291l0.035,-0.133l-0.045,-0.594l0.193,-0.049L736.676,427.431zM748.893,381.322l-0.023,0.141l-0.081,0.097l-0.225,0.054l-0.191,0.168l-0.304,0.243l-0.244,0.194l-0.177,0.172l-0.064,0.18l0.02,0.227l0.051,0.237l0.566,0.868l-0.005,0.15l-0.179,0.042l-0.238,-0.098l-0.205,-0.14l-0.231,-0.372l-0.186,-0.111l-0.185,-0.024l-1.1,0.191l-0.233,0.054l-0.363,0.139l-0.254,0.279l-0.185,0.255l-0.19,0.103l-0.278,0.198l-0.771,0.608l-0.445,0.262l-0.291,0.096l-0.204,0.138l-0.11,0.224l-0.083,0.161l-0.024,0.395l0.051,0.486l0.11,0.31l0.059,0.065l0.009,0.091l-0.111,0.167l-0.146,0.143l-0.071,0.088l-0.065,0.442l-0.129,0.217l-0.238,0.319l-0.211,0.241l-0.331,0.187l-0.126,0.151l-0.121,0.279l-0.071,0.236l-0.004,0.085l0.038,0.075l0.138,0.083l0.167,0.08l0.08,0.125l0.011,0.151l-0.124,0.363l-0.223,0.503l-0.255,0.398l-0.263,0.379l-0.063,0.124l-0.236,0.465l-0.206,0.639l-0.139,0.429l-0.12,0.294l-0.148,0.013l-0.179,-0.094l-0.437,-0.125l-0.279,-0.101l-0.203,-0.091l-0.141,0.004l-0.194,0.059l-0.197,0.041l-0.117,-0.044l-0.271,-0.265l-0.083,0.03l-0.053,0.129l0.183,0.756l0.119,0.281l-0.02,0.469l-0.047,0.575l-0.07,0.627l-0.047,0.145l-0.116,0.166l-0.153,0.045l-0.139,-0.065l-0.111,0.015l-0.037,0.105l0.032,0.271l-0.136,0.31l-0.1,0.265l0.026,0.257l0.048,0.261l0.159,0.564l0.001,0.206l-0.031,0.185l-0.083,0.077l-0.143,-0.013l-0.078,0.076l-0.059,0.116l-0.161,0.427l-0.154,0.045l-0.155,-0.064l-0.232,-0.285l-0.142,-0.083l-0.09,0.005l-0.04,0.075l-0.063,0.17l-0.063,0.114l-0.155,0.1l-0.038,-0.21l-0.083,-1.092l-0.063,-0.348l-0.051,-0.483l-0.075,-0.148l-0.096,-0.265L735,397.047l-0.089,-0.097l-0.057,-0.427L734.833,396l0.001,-0.248l-0.125,-0.513l-0.122,-0.582l-0.165,0.024l-0.098,-0.141l-0.071,0.003l-0.232,0.131l-0.185,-0.043l-0.137,0.018l-0.001,0.268l0.023,0.285l-0.052,0.103l-0.362,0.334l-0.101,0.224l0.01,0.235l0.045,0.314l-0.064,0.16l-0.157,0.147l-0.211,0.077l-0.186,-0.036l-0.119,-0.128l-0.111,-0.326l-0.099,-0.178l-0.104,-0.042l-0.081,0.048l-0.011,0.205l0.006,0.169l-0.026,0.019l-0.058,-0.026l-0.066,-0.083l-0.173,-0.818l-0.247,-0.631l-0.015,-0.242l0.09,-0.312l0.111,-0.481l0.293,-0.3l0.038,-0.127l0.048,-0.101l0.071,-0.02l0.376,0.028l0.126,-0.048l0.111,-0.142l0.162,-0.114l0.162,-0.046l0.129,-0.017l0.207,0.108l0.086,-0.062l0.063,-0.2l0.09,-0.198l0.058,-0.096l0.139,-0.043l0.177,-0.01l0.059,-0.037l0.048,-0.067l0.044,-0.263l0.226,-0.589l0.08,-0.262l0.012,-0.046l-0.007,-0.292l0.064,-0.042l0.375,0.143l0.164,-0.002l0.089,-0.059l0.029,-0.107l-0.048,-0.125l-0.267,-0.219l-0.474,-0.295l-0.435,-0.181l-0.804,0.027l-0.796,0.057l-0.233,-0.029l-0.291,-0.082l-0.715,0.012l-0.864,0.045l-0.329,-0.025l-0.162,0.003l-0.325,0.027l-0.53,-0.084l-0.367,-0.108l-0.325,-0.119l-0.386,-0.107l-0.093,0.001l-0.054,-0.039l-0.037,-0.095l-0.013,-0.123l0.08,-0.57l-0.071,-0.866l0.065,-0.316L727.469,387l-0.108,-0.132l-0.146,-0.006l-0.093,0.092l-0.037,0.167l0.053,0.187l-0.116,0.208l-0.233,0.067l-0.272,-0.07l-0.226,-0.098L726,387.203l-0.219,-0.299l-0.019,-0.331l-0.099,-0.213l-0.135,-0.104l-0.099,-0.029l-0.089,0.023l-0.078,0.116l0.068,0.115l0.093,0.162l-0.031,0.11l-0.083,0.017l-0.124,-0.047l-0.192,0.025l-0.186,-0.084l-0.111,-0.007l-0.11,-0.031l-0.007,-0.191l-0.169,-0.242l-0.286,-0.271l-0.281,-0.168l-0.135,0.023l-0.068,0.185l0.016,0.069l0.099,0.034l0.142,0.107l0.03,0.112l-0.021,0.098l-0.175,0.179l-0.124,0.17l-0.277,0.247l-0.236,0.283l-0.062,0.214l-0.089,0.192l-0.035,0.211l0.062,0.146l0.114,0.092l0.296,0.067l0.31,0.284l0.25,0.383l0.141,0.116l0.256,0.129l0.493,0.015l0.073,0.105l0.07,0.281l0.097,0.099l0.251,0.132l0.021,0.097l-0.061,0.112l-0.111,0.088l-0.205,0.056l-0.195,0.022l-0.196,-0.036l-0.291,-0.022l-0.33,-0.002l-0.234,0.699l-0.167,0.245h-0.095l-0.255,-0.119l-0.109,0.019l-0.294,0.62l-0.041,0.149l-0.02,0.112l0.156,0.239l0.187,0.197l0.223,0.077l0.175,-0.059l0.142,0.079l0.166,0.198l0.285,0.131l0.403,0.063l0.229,0.156l0.028,0.135l-0.02,0.137l-0.036,0.356l-0.039,0.205l-0.217,0.538l-0.155,0.463l0.08,0.22l0.058,0.09l0.055,0.069l0.174,0.173l0.121,0.171l-0.104,0.437l0.057,0.115l0.233,0.077l0.251,0.059l0.088,0.072l-0.218,0.443l0.046,0.308l0.092,0.289l0.066,0.472l0.01,0.05l-0.018,0.118l0.143,0.366l0.221,0.713l0.017,0.266l-0.013,0.281l-0.065,0.469l-0.221,-0.002l0.197,0.313l0.063,0.225l0.027,0.314l-0.237,0.039l-0.168,-0.035l-0.14,-0.275l-0.065,0.25l-0.25,0.231l-0.09,-0.113l-0.052,-0.121l-0.01,-0.214l0.138,-0.817l-0.028,-0.092l-0.062,-0.061l-0.137,-0.033l-0.051,-0.166l-0.209,0.872l0.092,0.356l-0.042,0.162l-0.39,0.136l-0.395,-0.327l-0.05,-0.105l-0.023,0.184l-0.071,0.224l-0.37,-0.041l-0.183,-0.175l0.119,-0.298l0.229,-0.72l0.043,-0.321l-0.307,-0.236l-0.26,-0.145l-0.149,-0.328l0.057,0.36l0.139,0.128l0.202,0.09l0.214,0.184l-0.154,0.224l-0.15,0.139l-0.287,0.528l-0.35,0.295l-0.408,0.222l-1.34,0.326l-0.281,0.132l-0.411,0.406l-0.266,0.385l-0.049,0.39l0.15,0.421l0.122,0.658l0.102,0.134l-0.143,0.24l-0.249,0.255l-0.206,0.343l0.019,0.188l-0.053,0.127l-0.706,0.421l-0.148,0.246l-0.194,0.244l-0.232,-0.14l-0.136,0.002l0.187,0.194l-0.024,0.128l-0.066,0.075l-0.178,0.07l-1.02,0.309l-0.78,0.293l-0.219,-0.012l0.04,-0.089l0.137,-0.079l-0.014,-0.336l-0.143,-0.062l-0.124,-0.024l-0.594,0.41l-0.24,0.405l0.05,0.077l0.135,-0.019l0.399,-0.229l0.186,0.065l0.013,0.09l-0.606,0.35l-1.275,1.132l-0.06,0.223l-0.166,0.252l-0.229,0.237l-0.411,0.573l-0.788,0.851l-0.219,0.317l-1.262,0.654l-0.23,0.194l-0.518,0.636l-0.532,0.52l-0.621,0.431l-1.077,0.549l-0.655,0.519l-0.205,0.345l-0.013,0.123l0.07,0.167l0.12,0.156l0.027,0.124l-0.059,0.222l-0.032,0.123l-0.192,0.304l-0.329,0.217l-1.065,0.453l-0.141,-0.014l-0.869,-0.09l-0.325,0.082l-0.134,0.212l-0.299,0.877l-0.286,0.233l-0.103,0.211l-0.041,0.146l-0.172,-0.004l-0.148,-0.065l-0.108,0.047l-0.124,-0.294l-0.208,-0.06l-0.172,-0.021l-0.734,0.296l-0.257,0.238l-0.54,1.121l-0.134,0.722l0.127,0.796l0.188,0.635l0.037,0.287l-0.023,0.372l-0.096,0.181l-0.068,0.214l0.09,0.441l0.227,0.577l0.055,0.244l0.005,0.251l0.171,0.576l-0.115,-0.104l-0.091,-0.243l-0.216,-0.31l-0.265,0.309l0.146,0.222l0.494,0.264l0.146,0.216l-0.318,1.921l-0.241,0.681l-0.296,0.446l-0.157,0.172L699.821,429l-0.244,0.851l-0.049,0.327l0.11,0.366l-0.125,0.216l-0.156,0.165l0.297,-0.074l0.102,0.198l0.038,0.205l0.004,1.216l-0.033,1.266l-0.229,0.052l-0.251,0.013l-0.222,-0.036l-0.159,-0.049l-0.396,0.067l-0.213,0.14l-0.171,0.232l0.012,0.396l-0.734,0.996l-0.158,0.332l-0.058,0.319l0.095,0.167l0.188,0.171l0.245,0.069l0.473,0.069l0.227,0.091l0.154,0.169l-0.557,-0.18l-0.655,-0.036l-1.566,0.462l-0.412,0.324l-0.23,0.281l-0.158,0.642l-0.027,0.429l-0.186,0.357l-0.813,0.548l-0.514,0.169l-0.195,0.146l-0.606,-0.189l-0.661,-0.48l-0.278,-0.258l-0.981,-1.24l-0.179,-0.157l-0.198,-0.531l-0.031,-0.198l-0.055,-0.079l-0.093,-0.054l-0.045,-0.082l-0.221,-0.608l-0.09,-0.634l-0.141,-0.709l0.118,0.049l0.164,0.233l0.082,0.339l0.01,0.474l0.123,0.055l0.11,-0.045l-0.315,-1.092l-0.274,-0.271l-0.072,-0.018l-0.077,-0.175l-0.008,-0.22l0.024,-0.104l-0.219,-0.358l-0.077,-0.213l-0.486,-1.083l-0.219,-0.777l-0.339,-0.865l-0.219,-0.303l-0.341,-0.668l-0.286,-0.311l-0.303,-0.417l-0.238,-0.185l-0.093,-0.097l-0.705,-1.447l-0.217,-0.801l-0.184,-0.378l-0.091,-0.288l-0.247,-1.231l-0.002,-0.22l-0.03,-0.241l-0.176,-0.522l-0.309,-0.565l-0.089,-0.352l0.001,-0.137l-0.196,-0.55l-0.042,-0.251l-0.132,-0.232l-0.154,-0.213l-0.16,-0.171l-0.377,-0.558l-0.135,-0.136l-0.257,-0.362l-0.183,-0.669l-0.234,-0.262h0.368l-0.225,-0.248l-0.106,-0.162l-0.118,-0.1l0.171,-0.25l-0.28,0.007l-0.148,-0.15l-0.203,-0.47l-0.369,-0.532l-0.063,-0.284l-0.326,-0.895l-0.276,-2.153l-0.253,-0.961l0.02,-0.276l-0.306,-0.834l-0.149,-0.56l-0.061,-0.475l-0.081,-0.312l-0.073,-0.62l-0.117,-0.196l-0.013,-0.118l0.078,-0.283l0.219,-0.437l0.081,-0.277l-0.095,-0.39l-0.199,0.41l-0.186,0.115l-0.089,-0.306l-0.001,-0.412l-0.023,-0.099l0.049,-0.138l0.492,0.063l-0.56,-0.253l-0.066,-0.148l-0.021,-0.111l0.12,-0.205l-0.204,-0.173l-0.082,-0.53l-0.06,-0.121l-0.023,-0.098l0.116,-0.733l0.482,-1.443l0.036,-0.327l-0.042,-0.465l-0.107,-0.37l-0.046,-0.392l-0.029,-0.101l-0.175,-0.036l-0.166,-0.145l-0.192,-0.582l0.176,-0.191l0.136,-0.105l-0.187,0.044l-0.154,-0.018l0.292,-0.269l0.261,-0.206l0.595,-0.239l0.253,-0.153l-0.374,0.138l-0.392,0.052l-0.832,-0.028l0.139,-0.544l0.145,-0.182l0.157,-0.102l-0.231,0.031l-0.268,-0.043l0.086,-0.553l0.211,-0.12l0.227,-0.023l0.282,-0.079l-0.302,-0.091l-0.313,-0.044l-0.377,0.091l-0.346,-0.067l-0.421,0.001l0.168,0.074l0.18,0.168l-0.09,0.3l-0.085,0.187l-0.231,0.129l-0.189,0.195l-0.053,0.171l-0.107,0.12l0.185,0.085l0.19,0.061l0.11,0.139l0.13,0.201l-0.007,0.391l-0.498,0.919l-0.172,0.205l-1.247,0.554l-0.489,0.301l-1.044,0.391l-0.406,0.073l-0.45,-0.078l-0.658,-0.297l-1.004,-0.761l-0.261,-0.251l-0.803,-0.979l-0.579,-0.519l-0.439,-0.483l-0.544,-0.458l-0.513,-0.618l-0.109,-0.282l0.038,-0.287l0.191,-0.156l0.224,0.063l0.177,0.242l0.125,0.108l0.105,0.044l0.766,-0.371l0.297,0.015l0.203,-0.186l0.257,0.041l0.524,-0.29l0.22,-0.018l0.262,-0.058l0.422,-0.735l0.316,-0.468l0.205,-0.098l-0.012,-0.114l-0.057,-0.149l-0.153,0.038l-0.107,0.142l-0.079,0.172l-0.08,0.103l-0.248,-0.095l-0.167,0.016l-0.206,0.056l-0.753,0.274l-0.31,0.246l-0.21,0.049l-1.203,-0.271l-1.176,-0.622l-0.495,-0.414l-0.313,-0.529l-0.313,-0.631l0.103,-0.177l0.486,-0.38l0.42,-0.299l-0.377,0.133l-0.408,0.185l-0.202,0.129l-0.229,0.271l-0.304,0.061l-0.12,-0.402l-0.076,-0.392l0.194,-0.132l0.136,-0.083l0.276,-0.07l0.302,-0.05l0.274,0.002l0.387,0.006l0.011,-0.92l0.032,-0.081l0.055,-0.047l0.063,-0.02l0.053,0.014l0.079,0.138l0.099,-0.008l0.105,-0.08l0.234,0.06l0.188,-0.041l0.19,0.054l0.324,0.001l0.585,-0.022l0.325,0.007l0.21,0.146l0.23,0.161l0.249,0.023l0.361,-0.019l0.245,-0.062l0.124,-0.15l0.093,-0.144l0.535,-0.21l0.562,-0.171l0.162,-0.019l0.051,0.1l-0.025,0.167l0.065,0.159l0.226,0.101l0.159,0.025l0.143,-0.023l0.106,-0.051l0.228,-0.25l0.118,-0.057l0.153,0.004l0.172,-0.12l0.003,-0.092l-0.109,-0.044l-0.093,-0.132l0.018,-0.107l-0.027,-0.152l0.019,-0.144l0.073,-0.108l0.128,-0.104l-0.076,-0.215l-0.196,-0.412l-0.205,-0.528l-0.217,-0.44l-0.275,-0.386l-0.142,-0.284l0.015,-0.627l-0.024,-0.127l-0.095,-0.078l-0.127,-0.043l-0.179,0.064l-0.161,0.012l-0.346,-0.014l-0.17,-0.064l-0.462,-0.631l-0.061,-0.248l-0.002,-0.255l0.153,-0.444l0.047,-0.414l0.021,-0.386l-0.025,-0.109l-0.093,-0.13l-0.155,-0.096l-0.415,-0.023l-0.493,-0.128l-0.379,-0.225l-0.264,-0.136l-0.071,-0.089l-0.032,-0.104l0.069,-0.469l0.119,-0.529l0.087,-0.162l0.15,-0.168l0.111,-0.114l0.178,-0.151l0.481,-0.506l0.431,-0.697l0.267,-0.487l0.139,-0.145l0.142,-0.124l0.207,-0.15l0.24,-0.137l0.238,0.006l0.226,0.125l0.168,0.146l0.057,0.323l0.119,0.209l0.128,0.126l0.17,0.061l0.217,-0.015l0.869,-0.37l0.296,-0.075l0.71,-0.046l0.487,-0.143l0.431,-0.15l0.053,-0.269l0.166,-0.411l0.506,-0.536l0.143,-0.239l0.153,-0.458l0.163,-0.418l0.141,-0.174l0.796,-0.46l0.779,-0.423l0.128,-0.192l0.504,-0.88l0.288,-0.599l0.075,-0.193l0.167,-0.521l0.181,-0.52l0.24,-0.121l0.535,-0.198l0.424,-0.194l0.218,-0.222l0.131,-0.194l-0.024,-0.192l-0.117,-0.228l0.024,-0.136l0.021,-0.134l0.309,-0.273l0.579,-0.809l0.348,-0.405l0.115,0l0.363,-0.216l0.345,-0.244l-0.02,-0.111l-0.043,-0.144l-0.198,-0.064l-0.063,-0.173l0.049,-0.248l0.166,-0.667l-0.034,-0.192l-0.202,-0.62l0.045,-0.171l0.083,-0.176l0.226,-0.234l0.291,-0.195l0.932,-0.462l0.189,-0.051l0.323,-0.117l0.198,-0.247l0.024,-0.211l-0.087,-0.131l-0.193,-0.176l-0.363,-0.159l-0.328,-0.139l-0.557,0.015l-0.289,-0.119l-0.079,-0.083l-0.04,-0.294l0.056,-0.498l-0.087,-0.044l-0.124,0.059l0.082,-0.039l-0.009,0.023l-0.232,0.057l-0.158,0.098l-0.388,-0.04l-0.187,-0.133l-0.28,-0.133l-0.213,-0.2l-0.334,-0.12l-0.28,-0.2h-0.427l-0.094,-0.2l-0.146,-0.134l-0.187,-0.16l0.08,-0.334l-0.12,-0.24l-0.04,-0.414l0.146,-0.174l-0.106,-0.427l0.066,-0.16l0.014,-0.2l-0.2,-0.2l0.014,-0.187l0.133,-0.16l-0.106,-0.414l-0.2,-0.2l0.014,-0.387l-0.04,-0.312l-0.134,-0.333l0.054,-0.333v-0.227l0.173,-0.187l0.294,-0.08l0.227,-0.093l0.014,-0.254l0.173,-0.307l0.188,-0.027l0.453,-0.013l0.16,-0.12l0.106,-0.4l0.12,-0.253v-0.267l-0.24,-0.24l-0.333,-0.147l-0.267,-0.08l-0.16,-0.12l-0.094,-0.2l0.054,-0.213l0.187,-0.12l0.08,-0.16l-0.134,-0.293l-0.28,0.013l-0.319,-0.04l-0.268,-0.08l-0.467,-0.04l-0.253,-0.232l-0.12,-0.24l-0.094,-0.347l-0.36,-0.173l-0.413,-0.094l-0.267,0.174l-0.294,0.013l-0.106,-0.16l-0.014,-0.293l0.066,-0.147l-0.066,-0.213l0.054,-0.213l0.133,-0.307l0.32,-0.227l0.334,-0.28l0.307,-0.333l0.293,-0.374l0.12,-0.374l0.268,-0.173l0.413,0.04l0.521,0.053l0.587,0.027l0.28,-0.067l-0.254,-0.28l-0.224,-0.124l0.09,-0.128l0.273,0.087l0.364,0.148l0.071,-0.014l0.043,-0.004l0.013,-0.007l0.029,-0.006l0.192,-0.121l0.202,-0.115l0.274,-0.125l0.539,-0.232l0.13,-0.068l0.03,-0.013l0.003,-0.002l0.16,-0.059l0.216,0.013l0.044,0l0.207,0.081l0.211,0.118l0.135,0.093l0.168,-0.056l0.128,-0.028l0.157,-0.049l0.127,0.034l0.116,0.022l0.143,-0.112l0.213,-0.08l0.214,0.106l0.227,0.333l0.267,0.387l0.163,0.106l0.297,0.078l0.281,0.156l0.078,0.083l0.164,0.174l0.013,0.017l0.132,0.243l0.051,0.092l0.213,0.255l0.374,0.347l0.44,0.146l0.347,0.36l0.213,0.187l0.36,0.04l0.307,0.334l0.014,0.24l-0.066,0.2l0.093,0.253l0.16,0.24l0.36,0.107h0.44l0.493,0.146l0.294,0.267l0.12,0.347l0.286,0.144l0.021,0.01l0.096,-0.006l0.404,-0.025l0.33,-0.075l0.464,-0.115h0.374l0.271,-0.427l0.307,-0.267l0.36,-0.08l0.294,-0.12l0.267,-0.2l0.467,-0.04l0.387,0.12l0.24,0.133l0.16,-0.093v-0.347l0.146,-0.173l0.24,-0.066l0.334,0.267l0.173,0.2l0.214,0.053l0.413,0.094l0.32,0.093l0.267,-0.12l0.188,-0.067l0.173,0.28l0.16,0.267l0.227,0.12l0.28,0.2l0.08,0.213l-0.066,0.227l0.04,0.24l-0.014,0.173l-0.12,0.227l-0.013,0.16l-0.134,0.187l-0.026,0.2l0.013,0.347l-0.106,0.267l-0.106,0.254l-0.08,0.187l-0.054,0.293l-0.2,0.107l-0.219,0.096l-0.28,0.134v0.267l-0.106,0.173l-0.253,-0.013l-0.28,0.013l-0.134,0.12l0.026,0.147l0.12,0.213l0.068,0.28l-0.116,0.5l-0.275,0.3l-0.167,0.066l-0.267,-0.066l-0.3,-0.1l-0.184,0.083l-0.267,0.05l-0.159,0.05l-0.066,0.158l0.059,0.233l0.1,0.208l0.117,0.192l0.184,0.3l-0.051,0.183l-0.142,0.125l-0.2,0.083l-0.033,0.184l0.025,0.217l0.35,0.477l0.334,0.35l0.63,0.042l0.016,0.104l-0.17,0.39l-0.007,0.172l0.27,0.299l0.063,0.287l0.175,0.143l0.087,0.296l-0.054,0.21l-0.273,0.071l-0.381,0.328l-0.241,-0.037l-0.02,-0.014v-0.017l-0.008,-0.187l0.008,0.208l-0.139,0.013l-0.119,0.071l-0.169,0.29l-0.195,0.076l-0.221,0.023l-0.228,-0.178l-0.187,-0.186l-0.051,-0.103l-0.047,-0.196l-0.101,-0.128l-0.194,0.06l-0.295,0.027l-0.319,0.043l-0.059,0.043l-0.006,0.083l0.078,0.176l0.066,0.229l0.04,0.32l0.086,0.212l0.027,0.067l0.511,0.636l0.134,0.129l0.028,0.085l-0.045,0.231l-0.092,0.27l0.019,0.214l0.17,0.236l0.138,0.165l-0.135,0.222l-0.08,0.257l0.09,0.115l-0.042,0.369l0.04,0.069l0.095,0.029l0.148,-0.025l0.154,-0.098l0.131,-0.019l0.078,0.028l0.104,-0.279l0.092,-0.04l0.178,0.077l0.352,0.526l0.298,0.444l0.063,0.061l0.023,0.023l0.053,0.051l0.294,0.23l0.203,0.145l0.277,-0.052l0.366,-0.01l0.217,0.142l0.125,0.099l0.006,0.014l0.017,0.003l0.44,0.348l0.19,-0.026l0.126,0.1l0.036,0.245l-0.059,0.255l0.014,0.12l0.196,0.023l0.417,0.168l0.368,0.149l0.191,0.047l0.205,0.11l0.182,0.176l0.355,0.226l0.314,0.173l0.069,0.234l-0.124,-0.05l-0.164,0.026l-0.167,0.104l-0.079,0.066l-0.381,0.403l-0.2,0.124l-0.179,0.181l-0.413,0.545l-0.239,0.508l-0.174,0.477l0.003,0.337l-0.064,0.395l-0.178,0.225l-0.109,0.076l-0.129,0.339l-0.093,0.395l0.054,0.128l0.222,0.172l0.216,0.168l0.275,0.182l0.264,0.173l0.17,0.022l0.047,-0.098l0.062,-0.094l0.194,0.05l0.236,0.169l0.154,0.135l0.068,0.045l0.408,0.227l0.338,0.187l0.428,0.237l0.104,0.145l0.092,0.154l0.202,0.204l0.491,0.361l0.42,0.259l0.342,0.21l0.268,0.147l0.124,-0.023l0.136,-0.079l0.119,-0.045l0.139,0.042l0.21,0.112l0.493,0.342l0.46,0.267l0.501,-0.048l0.133,0.043l0.094,0.242l0.063,0.245l0.56,0.162l0.368,0.073l0.421,0.133l0.213,0.099l0.224,-0.124l0.041,-0.109l0.177,-0.064l0.294,0.028l0.548,0.19l0.229,0.057l0.192,-0.18l0.357,-0.083l0.187,-0.094l0.39,0.2l0.704,0.25l0.363,0.156l0.086,0.153l0.039,0.145l-0.003,0.352l0.089,0.159l0.706,0.357l0.233,0.151l0.188,0.049l0.106,0.006l0.073,0.045l0.063,0.203l0.05,0.047l0.136,0.05l0.148,0.029l0.459,-0.176l0.314,-0.133l0.224,0.034l0.145,0.148l0.021,0.216l0.084,0.228l0.16,0.111l0.172,0.012l0.426,-0.154l0.343,0.118l0.314,0.043l0.35,0.074l0.136,0.056l0.362,0.188l0.443,0.19l0.171,-0.021l0.713,-0.354l0.061,0.043l0.145,0.338l0.217,0.121l0.339,0.106l0.354,-0.195l0.279,0.056l0.338,0.018l0.324,-0.094l0.281,-0.024l0.409,0.17l0.09,-0.039l0.078,-0.109l0.159,-0.488l0.141,-0.432l-0.013,-0.258l-0.129,-0.379l-0.331,-0.494l-0.024,-0.15l0.111,-0.863l0.123,-0.499l0.105,-0.236l0.116,-0.337l0.021,-0.156l-0.012,-0.141l-0.113,-0.086l-0.03,-0.107l0.028,-0.09l0.09,-0.05l0.376,-0.063l0.424,-0.135l0.169,-0.072l0.127,-0.072l0.13,-0.114l0.121,0.005l0.38,0.165l0.133,0.104l0.07,0.315l0.057,0.122L725,382l-0.228,0.774l0.045,0.289l0.189,0.211l0.165,0.147l-0.027,0.059l-0.34,0.249l-0.061,0.133l0.075,0.13l0.135,0.11l0.061,0.105l0.063,0.326l0.173,0.092l0.342,0.21l0.301,0.153l0.517,-0.102l0.146,0.069l0.254,0.072l0.198,0.022l0.115,0.054l0.064,0.052l-0.009,0.066l0.011,0.068l0.283,0.018l0.149,0.039l0.503,-0.07l0.505,-0.096l0.232,-0.291l0.103,-0.021l0.29,-0.113l0.286,0.124l0.314,0.169l0.17,0.051l0.335,0.027l0.326,-0.019l0.78,-0.081l0.429,0.042l0.394,-0.242l0.081,0.001l0.173,0.187l0.433,0.017l0.23,-0.09l0.248,-0.069l0.158,-0.022l0.127,-0.002l0.153,0.018l0.145,-0.062l0.066,-0.125l-0.015,-0.189l-0.104,-0.206l-0.091,-0.121l-0.018,-0.064l0.028,-0.149l0.08,-0.21l0.147,-0.24l-0.108,-0.233L733.87,383l-0.111,-0.026l-0.28,0.062l-0.303,-0.012l-0.239,-0.161l-0.178,-0.202l-0.043,-0.169l0.052,-0.207l0.079,-0.19l0.017,-0.071l0.227,0l0.314,0.042l0.238,0.053l0.191,-0.002l0.347,-0.244l0.158,-0.015l0.182,-0.046l0.079,-0.046l0.055,0.036l0.199,0.03l0.207,-0.012l0.185,-0.067l0.186,-0.105l0.33,-0.22l0.065,-0.126v-0.116l-0.062,-0.077l-0.063,-0.037l0.025,-0.101l0.139,-0.17l0.505,-0.256l0.43,-0.316l0.236,-0.237l0.108,-0.287l0.137,-0.312l0.128,-0.123l0.305,-0.078l0.854,-0.115l0.269,-0.126l0.397,-0.234l0.2,-0.184l0.111,-0.149l0.012,-0.166l0.264,-0.052l0.23,-0.269l0.279,-0.271l0.491,-0.229l0.435,-0.308l0.151,0.049l0.158,0.146l0.084,0.161l0.018,0.082l0.556,0.102l0.088,-0.016l0.409,0.144l0.377,0.174l0.208,0.043l0.102,-0.005l0.087,-0.054l0.102,-0.153l0.104,-0.111l0.065,-0.045l-0.003,-0.176l0.546,-0.344l0.49,-0.247l0.422,-0.18l0.124,0.074l0.137,0.137l0.187,0.349l0.113,0.085l0.286,-0.049l0.053,0.039l-0.045,0.125l-0.194,0.155l-0.252,0.139l-0.164,0.114l0.054,0.379l-0.013,0.13l0.071,0.041l0.518,-0.376l0.249,-0.074l0.089,0.091l0.027,0.201l0.205,0.414l0.087,0.21l-0.521,0.5l-0.191,0.258l0.007,0.091l-0.01,0.09l-0.133,0.128l0.007,0.051l0.107,0.081l0.131,0.061l0.063,-0.002l0.108,-0.121l0.491,-0.171l0.141,0.032l0.346,0.262l0.16,0.015l0.415,0.078l0.266,-0.099l0.195,0.091l0.405,0.328l0.093,0.06l-0.034,0.199l-0.021,0.219l0.103,0.174L748.893,381.322zM697.728,364.298l0.063,0.181l-0.055,-0.157L697.728,364.298zM679.961,431.122l-0.026,0.083l0.002,0.052l0.021,-0.018l0.021,-0.038l0.015,-0.073l0.008,-0.054l-0.009,-0.006L679.961,431.122zM680.784,439.432l-0.054,0.089l-0.048,0.028l-0.036,-0.03l-0.008,0.026l0.015,0.035l0.028,0.004l0.041,-0.013l0.04,-0.035l0.034,-0.067l0.011,-0.051l-0.011,-0.016L680.784,439.432zM735.329,432.104l-0.176,0.09l-0.217,0.205l-0.05,0.12l0.068,0.286l-0.021,0.292l0.289,0.076l0.085,-0.097l0.2,-0.424l-0.057,-0.271L735.329,432.104zM738.195,439.693l-0.105,-0.031l-0.105,0.149l0.013,0.178l0.024,0.101l0.005,0.056l0.019,0.08l0.033,0.014l0.132,-0.104l-0.071,-0.291L738.195,439.693zM738.646,441.953l-0.106,0.086l-0.113,0.061l-0.048,0.111l0.116,0.16l0.267,-0.266L738.646,441.953zM739.012,442.442l-0.389,0.149l-0.078,0.133l0.005,0.337l0.144,0.043l0.336,0.708l0.172,-0.231l0.11,-0.4l-0.198,-0.656L739.012,442.442zM737.757,440.245l-0.115,0.031l-0.07,0.121l0.092,0.125l0.064,0.121l0.218,-0.003l0.013,-0.06l-0.038,-0.139L737.757,440.245zM736.975,439.311l-0.054,0.061l-0.038,0.149l0.144,0.159l0.155,0.018l-0.084,-0.105L736.975,439.311zM736.691,428.877l-0.113,0.083l0.073,0.123l0.226,0.171l-0.125,-0.392L736.691,428.877 z"
},{
  id: "NP", "text":"default", "title": "Nepal", size: 70, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 722.979,381.675L723.092,381.761L723.104,381.902L723.083,382.058L722.967,382.395L722.861,382.631L722.738,383.13L722.627,383.993L722.651,384.144L722.982,384.637L723.111,385.017L723.124,385.274L722.983,385.707L722.824,386.194L722.746,386.304L722.656,386.343L722.247,386.173L721.966,386.197L721.642,386.291L721.304,386.272L721.024,386.216L720.671,386.412L720.332,386.306L720.115,386.185L719.971,385.846L719.91,385.803L719.197,386.157L719.026,386.179L718.583,385.989L718.221,385.8L718.085,385.744L717.735,385.67L717.421,385.627L717.078,385.51L716.652,385.664L716.48,385.651L716.32,385.54L716.236,385.313L716.215,385.097L716.07,384.949L715.847,384.915L715.532,385.048L715.073,385.224L714.925,385.194L714.789,385.144L714.739,385.097L714.676,384.894L714.603,384.849L714.496,384.842L714.308,384.793L714.074,384.642L713.368,384.285L713.279,384.126L713.282,383.774L713.243,383.629L713.157,383.476L712.794,383.32L712.09,383.07L711.7,382.87L711.514,382.964L711.156,383.047L710.964,383.228L710.734,383.17L710.187,382.98L709.893,382.952L709.716,383.017L709.675,383.125L709.451,383.249L709.238,383.15L708.817,383.018L708.449,382.945L707.89,382.783L707.826,382.539L707.732,382.297L707.6,382.254L707.099,382.302L706.639,382.035L706.146,381.692L705.936,381.58L705.797,381.539L705.678,381.584L705.542,381.663L705.418,381.686L705.15,381.538L704.809,381.328L704.389,381.069L703.897,380.708L703.695,380.503L703.604,380.35L703.499,380.205L703.071,379.968L702.733,379.781L702.325,379.555L702.257,379.51L702.103,379.375L701.866,379.206L701.672,379.156L701.61,379.25L701.563,379.348L701.394,379.325L701.13,379.152L700.854,378.971L700.639,378.803L700.417,378.63L700.363,378.502L700.456,378.107L700.585,377.768L700.694,377.692L700.872,377.467L700.937,377.072L700.934,376.734L701.107,376.257L701.347,375.749L701.76,375.204L701.938,375.023L702.139,374.899L702.52,374.496L702.599,374.43L702.766,374.326L702.93,374.3L703.054,374.35L703.181,374.561L703.335,374.762L703.522,374.752L703.741,374.58L704.195,373.79L704.826,373.628L705.424,373.71L705.953,373.825L706.109,374.089L706.211,374.368L706.277,374.509L706.451,374.675L707.197,375.069L707.63,375.424L708.229,375.9L708.677,376.109L709.074,376.127L709.298,376.313L709.635,376.684L709.92,377.109L710.275,377.502L710.521,377.489L710.856,377.362L711.265,377.195L711.506,377.277L711.729,377.386L711.803,377.589L711.938,377.973L712.086,378.371L712.32,378.51L712.598,378.714L712.751,378.876L713.271,379.174L713.344,379.295L713.449,379.377L713.576,379.429L713.681,379.49L713.845,379.511L714.445,379.333L714.605,379.355L714.697,379.388L714.7,379.453L714.592,379.731L714.5,380.087L714.595,380.265L714.847,380.339L715.403,380.392L716.154,380.387L716.383,380.567L716.609,380.837L716.838,381.298L716.929,381.493L717.042,381.549L717.237,381.472L717.27,381.283L717.278,381.001L717.442,380.904L717.547,380.976L717.669,381.196L717.979,381.394L718.204,381.491L718.418,381.457L718.508,381.381L718.613,380.996L718.782,380.94L718.995,380.965L719.077,381.042L719.163,381.196L719.422,381.269L719.679,381.365L719.92,381.491L720.261,381.776L720.68,381.829L721.167,381.822L721.423,381.829L721.611,381.85L721.78,381.83L722.279,381.626L722.483,381.611L722.736,381.634 z"
},{
  id: "LK", "text":"default", "title": "Sri Lanka", size: 20, "myColor": "default", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 700.169,435.179l0.27,0.015l0.288,-0.007l0.201,0.039l0.346,0.436l0.94,0.78l0.513,0.792l0.046,0.173l0.071,0.15l0.123,0.041l0.104,0.068l0.511,0.764l0.06,0.151l-0.009,0.167l0.03,0.124l0.134,0.062l0.166,0.032l0.109,0.115l0.139,0.609v0.19l0.039,0.081l0.644,0.947l0.037,0.115l-0.007,0.086l0.019,0.075l0.125,0.167l0.194,0.451l0.1,0.103l0.118,0.394l0.008,0.753l-0.044,0.334l-0.12,0.408l-0.143,0.398l-0.154,0.288l-0.211,0.243l-0.723,0.517l-0.207,0.104l-0.94,0.324l-0.693,0.306l-0.641,0.083l-0.642,-0.169l-0.482,-0.402l-0.247,-0.593l-0.17,-0.618l-0.245,-0.687l-0.189,-2.124l-0.09,-0.594l-0.146,-0.758l0.015,-0.329l0.104,-0.315l-0.001,0.691l0.096,0.086l0.071,-0.089l0.064,-0.716l0.053,-0.303l0.256,-0.79l0.005,-0.14l-0.044,-0.297l0.002,-0.149l0.382,-0.554l0.098,-0.323l0.053,-0.33l-0.021,-0.357l-0.068,-0.352l0.308,0.112l0.17,0.123l0.173,0.083l0.14,-0.042l0.17,-0.001l-0.121,-0.191l-0.358,-0.177l-0.595,-0.109l-0.186,-0.14l-0.071,-0.122l0.036,-0.142L700.169,435.179zM700.133,435.694l-0.176,0.031l-0.139,-0.188l-0.033,-0.08l0.037,-0.056l0.038,-0.028l0.045,0.009l0.066,0.175L700.133,435.694zM699.867,437.333l0.081,0.213l-0.231,-0.146l-0.152,-0.122l-0.055,-0.098l0.315,0.11L699.867,437.333 z"
},]
```

What is required is to put number inside the path element. Numbers are coming from API. or to mark arrow and put number if the path is too small to write down the number.

Please help me with this.

Comment: get the bounding box of the path via getBBox and then place the text accordingly.

Comment: Did you try using `textPath`? you might find this SO question useful "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67291003/add-text-to-svg-path-dynamically"

Comment: @Mohamed.Karkotly Tried but not working in my case also the id is dynamic to path tag.

Comment: @Manoj Fegde: please add some **visible** code e.g. actual `<path>`  data. If your map contains multiple paths (for regions/countries etc) you will also need stack all label elements on top to avoid hidden labels. (You can't apply `z-index` to svg elements to change stacking order)

Comment: @herrstrietzel - Check the update question.

Comment: as explained in the above mentioned link; ``textPath`` tied to your dynamic id is the way to go

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - textpath shows the text on the path. I need in the center of that path.

Comment: Text can be positioned anywhere you want, see all svg alignment options and pathLength. Multiple answers on SO

Comment: @Manoj Fegde: thanks for updating the question. You might split your question: Actually your question contains 3 tasks: 1. How to calculate label center coordinates 2. How to generate the appropriate svg code 3. How to implement this in Angular template syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to place text in text element and use text-anchor to center it:

```
<text *ngIf="item.myCheck=='true'" style="text-anchor: middle;">{{item.title}},
            {{item.size}}</text >
```

Comment: We cant put the text element in path element. Check the question completely.